# WPF shrinking child panel

Tags: resize

I'm working on a UI for a WPF application. I have in my window Stack Panel with some Expanders inside. In each Expander are some controls, one being a List Box. What I want to do is have the List Box resize (shrink or grow) when the window is resized. At the moment, when I re-size, the expander are getting clipped off but the listbox (sometimes very long in height) remains unchanged. How do I go about making this happen.

A good example is in Outlook 2007, the "Mail Folder" on the left shrinks with window size but the other controls don't.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be more specific, where would I start to creating the left panel similar to outlook, ie. when you re-size the menu bar, the buttons are hidden and an icon is added to the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Paul,

I've found something interesting myself.
I've extended the grid control with a simple method that fires when the expander is expanded, I would call this.

```
RowDefinitions[GetRow(expander)].Height = (expander != selectedExpander) ?
    new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) :
    new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
```

This worked very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The StackPanel won't push a height on its children - it allows each child to size as big as it likes. You might try using a Grid around the Expanders, and giving each Row a star height so that the contents resize.